# How can I anchor an ImageBrush to the bottom-left of an element?

Tags: wpf, imagebrush

I want to use an ImageBrush in a WPF element, and I want it to tile. But I want the image to line up with the bottom-left of the control, not the top-left. That is, instead of the top of the topmost tile being even with the top of the control, and a partial tile on the bottom end, I want it the other way around: the bottom of the bottom-most tile even with the bottom of the control, and a partial tile at the top. How can I do this?

Here's some XAML that repeats an image, but that anchors it to the control's top-left:

```
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Temp\triangle.png"
                Viewport="0 0 31 31"
                ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                TileMode="Tile"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Here's an illustration of what this does, and what I'm looking for (including what I want to happen as the element resizes):

[image]
<sub>(source: [excastle.com](http://www.excastle.com/misc/ImageBrushBottomLeft2.png))</sub>

How can I anchor the tiled images to the bottom of the element instead of the top (and make sure they stay anchored at the bottom, even as the element resizes)?

Answer (score 0):

The 'easiest' way is by calculating a other Viewport coordinates.

If the image is 20x20: Viewport="0 11 31 31" I could be wrong by a couple of units.

Comment: So apply a fixed offset? I meant "anchor" to mean "remain aligned, even as the element resizes", which a fixed offset wouldn't do. I edited my question to better explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess you will have to recalculate (perhaps by using a binding and valueconverter?)